# Designing/Visualizing a Mysql database to avoid rework

Tags: php, mysql, architecture

I have been coding php enterprise applications from many years but still i would like to take a feedback.

Usually when i get the functional specifications, i create a worksheet of how long it will take to finish the project. I don't have a team and i code start to end.

Almost in most of the big applications after reaching the midway, i figure out that the database should have been designed slightly in a different way. So i create or delete or modify few tables (sometimes more than few tables) for better optimization and data fetching.

So in my experience, i always have to do a rework somewhere in the mid way.

Below are the steps i follow for big applications.

1. Visualize the database. I prefer sketching them.
2. I have coded my own PHP MVC Framework and i use that.
3. Create unit tests (if required)
4. Do some optimization.
5. Code cleaning.
6. Deliver.

**My question:**
I was never taught programming. I learnt everything through mistakes and experiences and ofcourse Stackoverflow. Am i following the right pattern ? Or is there a better approach to avoid rework. I am sorry, my question might sound noobish, but i am seriously looking for some helpful advice.

Comment: Do you work by yourself? If you know anyone in your field that you trust, it is helpful to ask for other's opinions. I also spend a lot of time making sure that everything can scale well. Most applications remain unchanged until they are completely broken, so you should think about how long it will take for something to slow down or break. If you are displaying too much info, or making your server do too much work/create the entire page consider using ajax and let clients make their own pages. Create some kind of stress test for your design, and see what it takes to break everything.

Comment: **scale well** - i give that term utmost priority. Usually in my coding, i create modules. Each module is a feature, like a plugin. So adding features later on is not too much of a trouble. Just create a plugin. Less dependency. But what i consider more important is the base of the application. Database designing is what takes a lot of time. I keep getting this feel, that, oh this could have been done in a better way. I have a full time job in SAP but i do freelancing due to addiction.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha I had the same issue. I would only visualize the database and follow some of your steps and start coding. And after a while I would get stuck and realize that the database needs to be changed and hence rework. To solve this I started utilizing UML and along with database I started visualizing my classes and user requirements. And this has reduced a lot of rework. Hope this helps.

Comment: @JayBhatt very nice point.  Can you extend your answer please. I feel your point is making a concrete sense. Which software are you using to create UML diagrams. It will be very helpful if you can give some more details. Thanks Jay !

Comment: @AbhishekSaha I use SmartDraw. And explaining detailed steps would be too much. There are lots of tutorials out there from which you can easily learn. I would suggest that you start with a small system. Make the whole system on paper first (using UML diagrams) and then code. Look for Object oriented design.

Answer (score 1):

This ended up waaay too long for a comment...

1. Take StackOverflow with a grain of salt. Yes, there are some very smart, well-written answers, however there are also *many* cases of 'blind leading the blind'. You generally don't ask a question on SO if you know the answer, and if someone gets a terrible solution to their problem, but it works and they don't know any better, they can mark it as accepted like anyone else. There are a lot of people on this site in the mindset "if it's accepted, then it must be correct" and that will bite them in the ass eventually.
2. Find someone in your field that you *personally* respect and ask them to look over your DB design/methodology in detail rather than posing vague questions on SO. Your process *sounds* just fine in the broad strokes you've outlined, but who knows what kinds of devils are hiding in the details.
3. If there are certain small portions of code you'd still like to be reviewed by internet strangers you can try [CodeReview.StackExchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). CR questions on SO get closed faster than you can blink.

Comment: Well, yea, i do agree to your first point. That's very correct. I have myself got into arguments in few cases. And what i feel bad is that, users actually look for shortcuts in SO. They really don't learn. They just want a working solution. Your second point is something i really want to try, but i really don't know anyone in my vicinity who are of architect level and are passionate about coding. I will seriously try out the third option. I should have done this before. Thanks Mate.

Answer (score 1):

I think your steps are good. You may consider [posting some of your working code for review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get experienced programmers' opinions on design, best practices, etc. [There are also chat rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) with lots of active users who are specialists in specific languages, if you don't have an expert on hand.

Comment: I kind of feel confident on my way of coding. I have digged few frameworks and also wordpress in particular to learn good practices. But i will surely follow your advice and get some insight on my way of coding.